# Import third-party JavaScript library that normally self-executes into React app (using create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use a third-party library in my React app (built via `create-react-app`) that is normally loaded via a `<script>` tag in html file.:

> index.html

```
    ...
    <script src="some-library.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script basically just calls itself at the end of the file:

> some-library.js

```
function foo() {
  ...
}

foo();
```

There are no modules or `export` statements, so it's not immediately clear to me how to use this in my React app.

After installing the library with npm, I have tried using `import` and `require()` statements in my `App.js` file, without success:

> App.js

```
import "some-library";                          // doesn't work
require("some-library");                        // doesn't work
const SomeLibrary = require("some-library");    // doesn't work

...
```

Some instructions about using third-party libraries in React suggest using the library within one of the React lifecycle hooks, like `componentDidMount()`, but there's no function I'm able to call from the library:

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as SomeLibrary from "some-library";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SomeLibrary.foo();  // doesn't work (wasn't exported in "some-library")
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default App;
```

The only solution I've been able to find is to copy `some-library.js` into my `public/` folder, and then include it as a `<script>` tag in `index.html`. This seems like an awkward solution though.

**Is there a way to import this library in my `src/` JavaScript files for React instead of just as a `<script>` tag in `index.html`?**

(For reference, the specific library I'm trying to use is https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible/.)

Comment: I looked at the docs and the library doesn't seem to have any methods. As described under "Usage", add the script tag to your public index. Then add the CSS rule. As far as I can see, that's it. It's very possible however that it won't work for a React app, given that react keeps changing the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Chris G, I was able to get it working by importing the javascript file itself instead of just naming the npm package in node_modules. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to get this working by directly importing the file from the library's `dist` folder, instead of just naming the library by itself.

I also needed to make sure to import the library first before any other libraries (e.g. `React`).

> App.js

```
import "some-library/dist/some-library.js";
import React, { Component } from "react";
...
```

Comment: This helped me 6 years later! I needed the file `/node_modules/@orestbida/iframemanager/dist/iframemanager.js` and imported it via `import "@orestbida/iframemanager/dist/iframemanager.js"` (which is also worked for CSS `import "@orestbida/iframemanager/dist/iframemanager.css"`)